# Count number of objects in datastore AppEngine java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am trying to do a simple application that will persist an object every time a get request is made. In the below code, I use a servlet Put to accomplish this.

```
public class Put extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws IOException {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            PersistenceManagerFactory PMF = JDOHelper
                    .getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
            PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();

                String id = req.getParameter("id");
                String name = req.getParameter("name");
                String email = req.getParameter("email"); 
                String productId = req.getParameter("productid");
                String timeStamp =  new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());
                String mailSent = req.getParameter("mailsent");


                Product product = new Product(id,name,email,productId,timeStamp,mailSent);
                /*
                 * Get number of objects persisted till now
                 * Increment the count and use that value as key
                 */
                Key key = KeyFactory.createKey(Product.class.getSimpleName(),
                        "1001"); // ??
                product.setKey(key);
                try {
                    pm.makePersistent(product);
                } finally {
                    pm.close();
                }

        }
}
```

to retrieve all objects I use a Get servlet,

```
public class Get extends HttpServlet {
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        PersistenceManagerFactory PMF = JDOHelper
                .getPersistenceManagerFactory("transactions-optional");
        PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();

        /*
         * Get number of objects stored
         * loop from 0 to the count and print all objects
         * 
         */
            Product e = pm.getObjectById(Product.class, req.getParameter("id"));
            resp.getWriter().println();

    }
}
```

My problem is how to get number of objects stored in the datastore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be very careful about using counts in the datastore. All datastore operations are designed to scale with the size of the result set, not the size of the stored set of data. This means that there is no efficient way to count all the entities in your datastore.  In large distributed systems, it is difficult to maintain a strongly consistent count, you can see what is necessary to implement this for [sharded counters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters).

Additionally, you should not be storing your data using sequential keys. Additionally, you can run into performance problems by storing your data in sequential order. This is why the [default id allocation policy in Datastore switched to using scattered (non-sequential) ids](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.com/2013/05/update-on-datastore-auto-ids.html).

In order to loop over all of your entities, you should issue a [query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries) over your Product kind.

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Product.class);
try {
  List<Product> results = (List<Product>) q.execute();
  if (!results.isEmpty()) {
    for (Product p : results) {
      // Process result p
    }
  } else {
    // Handle "no results" case
  }
} finally {
  q.closeAll();
}
```

Note that as you get more entities, you'll eventually have too many entities to display on a single page. You should plan for this by setting limits and using [cursors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries#Query_Cursors) to implement paging.

If you want your results in date order, you'll have to order by your timestamp:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Product.class);
q.setOrdering("timestamp");
```

Also be careful that your query will be eventually consistent. This means that you may not see results in your query for some time after you `put` it. You'll want to make sure that if this is necessary you rethink your data design to [structure it for strong consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency).

Comment: Patrick, at your reputation of 999 I can't resist nudging you over 1k!

Comment: Well thank you! I've been bothering my coworkers with how excited I was to be so close.